Read in Batches with Open Csv library in Java
public Map<String, List> readCsv(MultipartFile customerCsvMultipartFile) throws IOException, CsvValidationException {
    List<CustomerCsvDto> customerCsvData;
    Map<String, List> migrationCsvMap = new HashMap<>();
    validateCsvFile(customerCsvMultipartFile);
    try (InputStreamReader customerReader = new InputStreamReader(customerCsvMultipartFile.getInputStream());) {
        CsvToBean<CustomerCsvDto> customerCsvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder<CustomerCsvDto>(customerReader)
                    .withType(CustomerCsvDto.class)
                    .withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true)
                    .build();
        customerCsvData = customerCsvToBean.parse();
        migrationCsvMap.put("customerCsvData", customerCsvData);
        return migrationCsvMap;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    }
}

I am using OpenCsv, and it provides a function to read the whole CSV to convert directly to my custom-defined DTOs using annotations @CsvBindByName(column = "csv_column_name") to map the column to the DTO property directly. I want to read the CSV in batches where I will pass the number of records I will read first process and then start after from the number I have read. How can I achieve batch reading using the OpenCsv in Java?

I couldn't find anything in the opencsv javadoc about batches. I think you will need to read your file in chunks and build lists of beans by reading those chunks. Have a look at FileChannel and ByteArrayInputStream. Use the former to get a file chunk as an array of bytes. Use the latter to get an InputStreamReader.

(shameless plug) If running on multiple threads, you might take some inspiration from https://github.com/skjolber/unzip-csv

@ThomasRS is there any advantages of multithreading here? Most of the time will be spend on reading file from disk anyway.

@ThomasRS thanks for the reference my second goal was to read it using a multithreading technique to optimize the memory.

You can get iterator using CsvToBean.iterator() and read how many records you want.
